# Bluehost shared hosting: can't connect to gmail smtp

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail, bluehost

in these last two weeks I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to connect my laravel application to gmail smtp. This is becoming quite frustrating.
The support is just bouncing us back and forth with no definitive help.

Application works perfectly when not on bluehost.

Here is the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@myaccount.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I've done different tests to ensure the settings were right. Both these tests were conducted on existing application and a fresh laravel install:

- Tested it on my local machine, application worked.
- Tested it on amazon aws, domain setup with godaddy, application worked.
- Tested it with and without MX settings in domain, application worked.
- Tested it using as "sender" a non-existent address (test.nonexisting@myaccount.com), of course I did not change the user/pass credentials. Application worked.
- On bluehost: nothing worked.

After the tests, i connected into my gmail account and the email were under the folder "sent". The receiving address had the email in his inbox.
I've been very careful in conducting the test and I'm mostly sure I'm not missing anything, but at this point I don't know what else to do.

**More info**

- I have a dedicated IP on my bluehost but I am on a shared hosting.
- Support says port 587 is up and running and not filtered.
- Can't telnet from bluehost.
- Using `sendmail` as `MAIL_DRIVER` is not a solution.
- MX in bluehost are setup correctly
- Nameservers are setup correctly
- Using port 465/ssl is not a solution (bluehost stated they block it).

**Yet more info** from the support team

```
PORT 587:
checksmtp smtp.gmail.com 587 user@myaccount.com
<mailto:user@myaccount.com> 

depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN =
smtp.gmail.com
verify return:1
250 SMTPUTF8
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dmFjYXRpb25zQHZhY2F0aW9uc2l0YWx5LmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Q2FyYXZhZ2dpbzAxIQ==
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

The php error output:

```
Connection timed out (110)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can check if the port is reachable using fsockopen

Comment: fsockopen is not available in the shell, but please, see edit above.

Comment: fsockopen is a php function

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Will check in it asap

Comment: @Devon Forgot to comment but the error is the same, 110 timed out

Comment: Well,  that's your answer there, for whatever reason you can't establish a connection to that host/port.